# Why is MouseAdapter an adapter?

Tags: java, design-patterns

The name (and javadocs) imply that `MouseAdapter` is an adapter (the design pattern). But I don't see it as such - it doesn't adapt anything to anything, at first sight at least

The only adaptation that happens is that you can pass an instance of `MouseAdapter` to any method that expects either of the interfaces. So, you make it possible to use a `MouseListener` instance where only `MouseMotionListener` is expected. But there is no "translation" happening. And it does not conform to the UML of GoF - in the "class adapter" version it is expected that a call to one method invokes a method from the adaptee.

So, is that an adapter (design pattern), or is it just a random name that causes confusion?

Comment: Just for future reference, and because I didn't know myself; **GoF** refers to  the *"Gang of Four"* ; namely Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson, and John Vlissides who are the authors of "Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`MouseAdapter` first appeared in Java 1.1 released in [Feb 1997](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#JDK_1.1_.28February_19.2C_1997.29). This means that it was developed sometime in 1996 (or 1995?)

UML (in its draft) was [completed by 1997](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language#History).

The first GoF book on design patterns was [published in 1995](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_%28book%29).

So, I don't think that *Adapter* in `MouseAdapter` had anything to do with the corresponding design pattern. Or, even if it did, developers just had no unified language to express design patterns which would make it very hard to comprehend the real meaning.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is not an adapter in the sense of GoF pattern because it does not adapt anything.
It can be considered an instance of Abstract Class pattern [[woolf97](http://hillside.net/plop/plop97/Proceedings/woolf.pdf)]:

> The superclass may provide a complete implementation that is a default
>   or minimal implementation.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have said, it's not a GoF Adapter pattern. The main purpose of it is to enable one to implement `MouseListener` (or `MouseMotionListener`) by over-riding just the desired methods in `MouseAdapter` (often just `mouseClicked()`) rather than having to create pointless empty implementations of all the other methods. It therefore saves a lot of unnecessary code, especially when using anonymous event listeners. For example (taken from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/generalrules.html))

```
    someObject.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            ...//Event listener implementation goes here...
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know there is already an accepted answer for this question, but this same question was asked here:

[MouseAdapter: which pattern does it use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302636/mouseadapter-which-pattern-does-it-use/8315910#8315910)

See there for more deatils, but the MouseAdapter **adapts** the very awkaward MouseListener interface into a more usable form.

Comment: The problem with this reasoning is, as other answers indicate, there are no pre-existing adaptees in the MouseAdapter situation. GoF Adapter's Motivation (I'm quoting the GoF book) is "Sometimes a toolkit class that's designed for reuse isn't reusable only because its interface doesn't match the domain-specific interface an application requires."  MouseAdapter is an *adapter* because it can easily be adapted (customized) to capture mouse events. GoF Adapter says you have some *legacy class* (toolkit) you can't change, so you adapt its interface to your application's need.