# What is an adaptor in the C++ standard? How does it relate to the adapter design pattern?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, adapter, standards, std

The C++ standard uses the word *adaptors* several times:

- Allocator adaptors (`std::scoped_allocator_adaptor`)
- Container adaptors (`std::queue`, `std::priority_queue`, `std::stack`)
- Iterator adaptors (`std::reverse_iterator`, `std::move_iterator`)

It does not seem that the word itself is defined in the standard. I was thinking that the word was used in reference to design patterns, but it seems that in the [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) design pattern, the adapter should only adapt the interface, not the behavior.

**Questions:** Therefore I was wondering:

- What would be the approximate definition of an adaptor in the C++ standard?
- Does it correspond to the adapter design pattern?
- If not, what would be the design pattern that matches the best what an adaptor is in the C++ standard (adapter, proxy, facade, decorator...)?

Comment: I suspect most of those predates [the book of 4 book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) that coined the name.

Comment: *facade* might be best.  It implements a particular interface on top of an already defined thing.

Comment: Fun Fact: we see the same phenomenon in the Java world with old classes like [MouseAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244185/why-is-mouseadapter-an-adapter). A sign of the times?

Comment: @jaco0646 I just looked into the old history of C++. The word adaptor for iterators was already used in 1994. For containers it's the case in 1995.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The word "adapter" is not used in some technical, design-pattern sense. It is used as the English word: a thing that adapts. There is no need for a more rigorous definition than that.

Container adapters modify the interface of containers. Iterator adapters modify the interface of iterators. And so forth. You're really overthinking the whole thing.